# How to configure PhpStorm to use LESS

Tags: configuration, less, phpstorm

I would start to use LESS so I try to configure my **PhpStorm v8.0.3** to automatically compile `.less` into `.css` files.

I have installed `node.js` and installed less ( `npm install -g less` ), then I tried to set IDE but I obtained errors.

In Program input I don't know what write, if I leave empty the program say

> "Please set program to run!"

If I use a macro the most of time I obtain error permissions

> "error = 13"

Comment: 1) Your OS? 2) Please provide screenshots of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You need less plugin for phpstorm https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7059?pr=idea after install restart phpstorm and open .less file
Phpstorm suggest you to add File Watcher for compiling less files automatically.

Comment: You do not really need that plugin -- IDE is fully capable of compiling LESS into CSS using actual LESS (`lessc`) and File Watchers plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point your `Program` field to your `lessc` file (`lessc.cmd` on Windows).

Here is what I'm using on Windows:
[image]

**P.S.**
I'm keeping my `.less` files in `/assets/less/` folder and compiled files in `/assets/css/` -- hence the `../css/` part in file output paths. If you want to keep compiled files next to sources .. then just remove that part.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm

Comment: i had installed the plugin and after i have set program input with this path: /Users/gabrielecontiello/Desktop/lessc-plugin/lib/lessc-plugin.jar .

Unfortunaly if i try to modify a.less file i obtain this erro: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar /Users/user/Desktop/lessc-plugin/lib/lessc-plugin.jar --no-color style_bk.less

Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from /Users/user/Desktop/lessc-plugin/lib/lessc-plugin.jar

Is correct to select .jar file (i have a mac)?

Where i wrong?thanks for help

Comment: @GabrieleContiello 1) This plugin is NOT developed by JetBrains -- so if you need help with THAT plugin -- contact author; 2) You do not need that plugin -- IDE can compile `.less` files without it; 3) This plugin has no relation to my answer -- my answer is about File Watchers and not 3rd party custom plugin.

Comment: sorry! was my intentions to comment funivan post. About your answer.I have doubt about path of Program input. 1) I need to download lessc.cmd  or is located naturaly in npm path? 2) i have a mac do you know what exstension has the lessc and where is located ? i can't find it. Thanks for help

Comment: 1) It's a Mac -- `lessc` has no extension. 2) You do not know how to use Search functionality to find files on your hard drive? In any case: `which lessc` ?